# Refactor Using RegEx or Bash Script

Tags: bash

I would like to run through files residing inside directories that are deeply nested and change parts of it to something else.
For instance, I would like to change in a file any part that has

```
className={styles.badgeRight}
```

to

```
className="badgeRight"
```

I could do this manually but there are thousands of files so a script or some RegEx would do. How would I go about achieving this?

Pretty much just taking anything exactly after the dot and wrapping it in quotes and removing the JSX brackets and the word `styles`.

Comment: What have you tried? It's difficult to know what you're aiming for if you don't include sample input and intended output that people can test solutions against. And include your own code! This isn't a forum for hand-outs, we *really* want to help you fix your own code. Aim for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You're right. I get that. I think my question was clear enough with no need for example code, or at least the example that I provided was enough. And @simon3270 has answered it correctly. Some question are clearly and need not be cluttered with unnecessary code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple in-place "sed" edit of the file will work. This will create backup files (adding ".bak" to the original name). To avoid that, just replace `-i.bak` with `-i`:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak 's/className={styles\.\([^}]*\)}/className="\1"/' {} +
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I've updated the answer to change the "\;" on the "-exec" to a "+" - this will runone "sed" for many files, rather than once for each file. There are 1000s of files. That, or my original "xargs" would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First use `find` command to list all the files and store it in a `list_of_file.txt` file

```
 find /your/directory/path/*.txt > list_of_file.txt
 # change file extension type from txt to your own type example *.java
```

now use a `while loop` and use `sed` command to modify the script

```
 while read file
 do
     sed -i.bak 's/className={styles\.\([^}]*\)}/className="badgeRight"/g' $file
 done < list_of_file.txt
```

Comment: This is not specific to just badgeRight but meant to take anything that comes after the dot and wrap it in quotes.

Comment: @brandNew, I have modified my answer it will work for you.

Comment: Completed the update required to match any string after "styles." and use that string in the final text. This still calls sed once for each file, so will be quite slow. Better to use xargs (which calls one `sed` command with as many filenames as will fit on a command line), or the `-exec` option of `find` with the trailing `+`. Also you need to quote "$file" on the command line, in case it contains spaces etc.